# does spark have the ability to parallise regular python function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

can I use spark to do a regular python job in parallel? for example:

```
def my_f(mylist1, mylist2):
 #sophisticated stuff
 return map(lambda x: x + 1, mylist1)


mylist3 = my_f(xrange(10), xrange(5))
#pass my list to a spark rdd for further processing
```

The reason im asking is because in my pipeline I need to use a sklearn model on 2 arrays and I want to take those output for further manipulation in spark

Comment: I guess you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.